# php inside javascript - No Contents found

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm trying to integrate a js slideshow fade effect with php. It was working fine, but not anymore, I'm not sure what has changed. Now it shows an alert that says "No contents found". The connection to the database should be ok, there is content being displayed in other areas of the page.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>  
     $(function () {  
         $("#blogSlider").codaSlider();  
     });  
 </script>  
</head>

<body>
<div class="navheader">
</div>

<div class="header2"><p class="headlineblack">

<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Home", $connection);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row["blurb"];
  }
?>
</p>
    </div>

 <div class="container">
  <p class="subheadgrey"><img src="images/grafix_down_small.png" width="30" height="22" /> Case studies</p>
  </div>


<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript">

var slsContents = new Array();

                             <?php  

$query = "SELECT * FROM studies";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);


$query_data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $query_data[0];


$num=mysql_numrows($result);

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$title=mysql_result($result,$i,"title");
$strategies=mysql_result($result,$i,"strategies");
$client=mysql_result($result,$i,"client");
$copy=mysql_result($result,$i,"copy");
$thumbmedia=mysql_result($result,$i,"thumbmedia");
$niche=mysql_result($result,$i,"niche");

echo 'slsContents['.$id.'] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id='.$id.'\">'.$title.'</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +';
echo                                  '"<div class=\"column1\">" +';
echo                                   ' "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">'.$strategies.'</p>" +';
echo                                    '"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +';
echo                                   '"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +';
echo                                   '"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">'.$client.'</p>" +';
echo                                  '"</div>"+';
echo                                '"<div class=\"column2\">" +';
echo                                   '"<p class=\"bodygrey\">'.substr($copy, 0, 300).'<a href=\"casestudy.php?id='.$id.'\">...more</a></p>" +';
echo                              '"</div>" +';
echo                                  '"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";';


$i++;
}

?>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow/slideshow.js"></script>


                         </div>  
                     </div>
```

**EDITED:
this is what comes up in the source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var slsContents = new Array();

                             slsContents[1] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=1\">man</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"><a href="strategies.php?strategy=Asking_a_question_when_you_already_know_the_answer">Asking a question when you already know the answer</a></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">NZTrio</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">ftyiuutf<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=1\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[2] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=2\"></a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">Select a Client...</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=2\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[3] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=3\">title three</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">and this one too</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">client c</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">today qw we wnt to the resene tshoep and sdurkngk some salcohol and anoe i'm kinkdo of drunk and alluan uwnat ts met ot do wealy data wentyr and i can't trnkdyfp<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=3\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[4] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=4\">title four</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">client d</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">Despite international critical acclaim and rave reviews, NZ Trio's concerts just weren't pulling in the crowds. 4i's helped the trio identify a more promising niche market and repackage its product offering to appeal directly to the new audience. The turnaround marketing strategy, which employed a n<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=4\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[5] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=5\">title five</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">and this one too</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">client e</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">today qw we wnt to the resene tshoep and sdurkngk some salcohol and anoe i'm kinkdo of drunk and alluan uwnat ts met ot do wealy data wentyr and i can't trnkdyfp<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=5\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[6] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=6\">Title six</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"><a href="strategies.php?strategy=Turkey_Basting">Turkey Basting</a> // <a href="strategies.php?strategy=Asking_a_question_when_you_already_know_the_answer">Asking a question when you already know the answer</a></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">NZTrio</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">Despite international critical acclaim and rave reviews, NZ Trio's concerts just weren't pulling in the crowds. 4i's helped the trio identify a more promising niche market and repackage its product offering to appeal directly to the new audience. The turnaround marketing strategy, which employed a n<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=6\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[7] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=7\">Title seven</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">and this one too</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">client g</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">today qw we wnt to the resene tshoep and sdurkngk some salcohol and anoe i'm kinkdo of drunk and alluan uwnat ts met ot do wealy data wentyr and i can't trnkdyfp<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=7\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[9] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=9\">title nine</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">and this one too</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">client i</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">today qw we wnt to the resene tshoep and sdurkngk some salcohol and anoe i'm kinkdo of drunk and alluan uwnat ts met ot do wealy data wentyr and i can't trnkdyfp<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=9\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[10] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=10\">title ten</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">client j</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">Despite international critical acclaim and rave reviews, NZ Trio's concerts just weren't pulling in the crowds. 4i's helped the trio identify a more promising niche market and repackage its product offering to appeal directly to the new audience. The turnaround marketing strategy, which employed a n<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=10\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[11] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=11\">title eleven</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">and this one too</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">client k</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">today qw we wnt to the resene tshoep and sdurkngk some salcohol and anoe i'm kinkdo of drunk and alluan uwnat ts met ot do wealy data wentyr and i can't trnkdyfp<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=11\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[12] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=12\">Title twelve</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">Client l</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">Despite international critical acclaim and rave reviews, NZ Trio's concerts just weren't pulling in the crowds. 4i's helped the trio identify a more promising niche market and repackage its product offering to appeal directly to the new audience. The turnaround marketing strategy, which employed a n<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=12\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[13] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=13\">Title thirteen</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">and this one too</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">client m</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">today qw we wnt to the resene tshoep and sdurkngk some salcohol and anoe i'm kinkdo of drunk and alluan uwnat ts met ot do wealy data wentyr and i can't trnkdyfp<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=13\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[15] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=15\">Title fifteen</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">and this one too</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">Client o</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">today qw we wnt to the resene tshoep and sdurkngk some salcohol and anoe i'm kinkdo of drunk and alluan uwnat ts met ot do wealy data wentyr and i can't trnkdyfp<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=15\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[16] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=16\">Title sixteen</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">client p</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">Despite international critical acclaim and rave reviews, NZ Trio's concerts just weren't pulling in the crowds. 4i's helped the trio identify a more promising niche market and repackage its product offering to appeal directly to the new audience. The turnaround marketing strategy, which employed a n<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=16\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[17] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=17\">title seventeen</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">and this one too</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">client q</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">today qw we wnt to the resene tshoep and sdurkngk some salcohol and anoe i'm kinkdo of drunk and alluan uwnat ts met ot do wealy data wentyr and i can't trnkdyfp<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=17\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[18] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=18\">fghj</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">empty</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">lk'dfx<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=18\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[19] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=19\">evry time</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">hmm</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">Gary Busey</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">why don't it<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=19\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[20] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=20\">fdgh</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">Gary Busey</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">sfgh<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=20\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[21] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=21\">mr</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">Gary Busey</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">xsdfgh<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=21\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[22] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=22\">fgj</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">empty</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">fdghj<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=22\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[23] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=23\"></a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">empty</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=23\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[24] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=24\">dfg</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">empty</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">sdfg<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=24\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[25] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=25\">ghjk</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">empty</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=25\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";slsContents[26] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=26\">fudget</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"></p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">empty</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=26\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";</script>
```

With the new changes, this is the new source:

```
var slsContents = new Array();

                             slsContents[28] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\"><a href=\"casestudy.php?id=28\">If we needed proof that enthusiasm is infectious...</a></p></div><div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\"><a href=\"strategies.php?strategy=
Viral_marketing\">
Viral marketing</a></p>" +"<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +"<p class=\"sidebargrey\">empty</p>" +"</div>"+"<div class=\"column2\">" +"<p class=\"bodygrey\">Approaching the close-off of applications for post-graduate study positions for the year, The University of Auckland’s National Institute of Creative Arts & Industries (NICAI) still had some places to fill.<br />  
<br />
While the problem was essentially one of lead generation, the number of ca<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=28\">...more</a></p>" +"</div>" +"<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";
```

Comment: Some basic troubleshooting: Have a look at view source in the browser?

Comment: see edit above - thanks. 

So, it is getting the content from the database, just not displaying for some reason

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be a problem with your generated JavaScript, if you look on the line below, you will see that there is a href without an escaped " in it.

on the 5th line of the code below you have

```
<a href="strategies.php?strategy=Asking_a_question_when_you_already_know_the_answer">
```

This looks to be coming from the database, and sorted in the *$strategies* var, I would suggest you do a [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on all the output from the database to replace " with \"

like so

```
$strategies = str_replace  ('"', '\\"' , $strategies);
```

**Code from your output**

```
slsContents[1] = "<div class=\"container\"><p class=\"subheadred\">
                  <a href=\"casestudy.php?id=1\">man</a></p></div>
                  <div class=\"containerstudy\">" +"<div class=\"column1\">" + 
                 "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Strategies</p><p class=\"sidebarred\">
                 <a href="strategies.php?strategy=Asking_a_question_when_you_already_know_the_answer">
                 Asking a question when you already know the answer</a></p>" +
                 "<p class=\"sidebargrey\"><a href=\"link\">Target market segmentation // marketing strategy and execution</a></p>" +
                "<p class=\"subheadsmall\">Client</p>" +
               "<p class=\"sidebargrey\">NZTrio</p>" +"</div>"+
               "<div class=\"column2\">" +
               "<p class=\"bodygrey\">ftyiuutf<a href=\"casestudy.php?id=1\">...more</a></p>" +
                "</div>" +
                 "<div class=\"column3\"><img src=\"images/tn_tereoposter.jpg\" width=\"275\" height=\"160\" /></div></div>";
```

Comment: Incredible! that is awesome. It's working great on my computer, but it still says the same thing on my host server. any ideas? I've edited the new source into the question above